# Как запустить отладку для всего кода в PyCharm БЕЗ проставления точек останова

Tags: pycharm

У меня возник вопрос. Весь интернет перерыл, не смог найти. У меня есть код на 4000 строк, и я хочу запустить его отладку. Мне приходиться на каждой строке проставлять точки останова. Это бред полный. Поэтому мой вопрос - можно ли как то запустить код без точек останова? Либо подскажите, как проставить точки останова сразу на все строки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поставь брейкпойнт на первую строчку, а потом нажимай Step Over или F8.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое:)